# How to perform the MaxSim operator leveraging torch procedures?

Tags: pytorch, torch, array-broadcasting, numpy-einsum

Let `T` and `L` be two batches of matrices `(MxN)` and a function `f(ti,lj)` that calculates a score for matrices `ti` and `lj`.  For instance, if

```py
T, L= torch.rand(4,3,2), torch.rand(4,3,2)
# T = tensor([[[0.0017, 0.5781],
#          [0.8136, 0.5971],
#          [0.7697, 0.0795]],

#         [[0.2794, 0.7285],
#          [0.1528, 0.8503],
#          [0.9714, 0.1060]],

#         [[0.6907, 0.8831],
#          [0.4691, 0.4254],
#          [0.2539, 0.7538]],

#         [[0.3717, 0.2229],
#          [0.6134, 0.4810],
#          [0.7595, 0.9449]]])
```

and the score function is defined as shown in the following code snippet:

```py
def score(ti, lj):
    """MaxSim score of matrix ti and lj
    """
    m = torch.matmul(ti, torch.transpose(lj, 0, 1))
    return torch.sum(torch.max(m, 1).values, dim=-1)
```

How to return a score matrix `S`, where `S[i,j]` represents the score between `T[i]` and `L[j]`?

```py
#S = tensor([[2.3405, 2.2594, 2.0989, 1.6450],
#            [2.5939, 2.4186, 2.3946, 2.0648],
#            [2.9447, 2.3652, 2.3829, 2.1536],
#            [2.8195, 2.3105, 2.2563, 1.8388]])
```

**NOTE**: This operation must be differentiable.

Comment: Are you asking for a vectorized operation? Your question only says torch procedures, which are already used in the `score` function.

Comment: Hello @kmkurn. However, I would have to perform a nested for loop through every pair (ti, lj) of matrices from T and L and store the scores for each pair in a temporary array. So, I don't know if all this would be differentiable (to be used during the training of a neural network)

Comment: Yes, a nested loop will do. I think it will be differentiable if you use something like `torch.cat` to concatenate the results. So, to clarify, you are OK with having a nested loop as long as the result is differentiable?

Comment: Can you please also add the `L` matrix, so we can verify the test cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend using `einsum` for the pair wise matrix multiplication

```
m = torch.einsum('b i j, c k j -> b c i k', T, L)
```

which results in

```
>>> m.shape
torch.Size([4, 4, 3, 3])
```

that is, a tensor that contains all 16 matrix products. Then the rest is simply

```
out = torch.max(m, -1).values.sum(dim=-1)
```

Alternatively you could use [broadcasting](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/broadcasting.html) for the matrix multiplications, but I think it is quite a bit more cumbersome than the `einsum` solution.

Comment: Wow what an elegant solution, I didn't even know this was possible. This is definitely a solution.